# differents result FullTextSearch Contains and like

Tags: sql, full-text-search, sql-like, containstable

I've put the content of pdf files into a table.
I've searched with

```
SELECT * FROM Doc WHERE Content LIKE '%blitz%
```

It found 78

```
SELECT * FROM Doc WHERE CONTAINS(Content, '"*blitz*"')
```

it found 72

I've opened the PDFs that the contains don't find as result, and the word blitz is in it.

> Telefon / EDV / Pot. / Blitzschutz
>
> SpenglerBlitzschutz

How can write the perfect equivalent of like '%word%'

I didn't find many help from google. And it's the first time that I want to use a Full Text Search Catalog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full Text search**, as the name depicts, indexes full words and is way faster than **LIKE** operator when searching text in large text files.
**LIKE** operator will always scan everything in text(Including Spaces) on the other hand **Full Text Search** will index based on full words and will show results based on full words. You have a way to tell SQL Server which characters/words to be treated as **Noise Words** by using **Stop List**(A configurable file in system).
For more information on Stop Lists: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search

Some more info about CONTAINS:
CONTAINS can search for:

1. A word or phrase.
2. The prefix of a word or phrase.
3. Word forms (like superlative degree of word) example: drives, drove, driving, and driven will show when you search for drive.
4. Synonyms.

**In your case** I would say that you will have to use **LIKE** operator separately to get those 5 words, as contains won't be able to search them (Unless of course full words are specified).

Comment: It doesn't explain why the Telefon / EDV / Pot. / Blitzschutz, do you think, it pretend to be just one word?

Comment: @Monica : You searched for 'blitz' but none of the 4 words resemble to 'blitz' in any manner (I don't think 'Blitzschutz' and 'blitz' relate to each other in terms of language).

Comment: but it starts with blitz.
Does the / make any difference?

Comment: Whole word needs to match or should be a synonym.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuild FTS index https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326034(v=sql.105).aspx . If decadency still exist provide us exact words CONTAINS did not get.